# Facebook Search API returning empty json

Tags: facebook-graph-api

The Facebook search API (`https://graph.facebook.com/search`) seems to return an empty string even when fed with correct data.

A call like `https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Joe&type=user&access_token=EAAH8mO348PABAKZCmuqftCrlBbqxNvpxzJiCywVgeAxLgKfMs432GpZC8Xd2yvrXNm7OoWbZAsjOs8LOfJ8BGMMcvJQZCVG1LIHjdVZAr1Gks1ZB5nn7guZBAauPZCdIi16A6cK3vX0i1pLhY3bVZCNSkOG7TkEqaMZBnyIPf0UMo5uzsJsIWXo1J251rDlyMtEpMYTWUcaHOOK6aIJu1vzPZAr` (using my access token) doesn't return anything.

The token is valid. I have pasted it directly from the facebook developers console.

Can you help me out?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible anymore

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#search-4-4

> You can no longer use the /search endpoint with the following object
>   types:
>
> - event
> - group
> - page
> - user

Comment: This makes me mad, it worked until 3 days ago